# finalizar un PolyLine y abrir otra activity en kotlin y google maps

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, kotlin

Mi pregunta es desde mi ubicacion y al llegar al objetivo finalizar la polylinea y lanzar otra activity comparto mi codigo

```
private fun cargarURL(url:String){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val solictud = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {
        response ->
        Log.d("HTTP", response)
        val coordenadas = ObtenerCoordenadas(response)

        if (rutaMarcada != null){
            rutaMarcada?.remove()
        }

        rutaMarcada = mMap.addPolyline(coordenadas)

    }, Response.ErrorListener {  })
    queue.add(solictud)
}

private fun ObtenerCoordenadas(json:String): PolylineOptions {
    val gson = Gson()
    val objeto = gson.fromJson(json, com.voxpop.juckevox.juckevox.Response::class.java)
    val puntos = objeto.routes?.get(0)!!.legs?.get(0)!!.steps!!

    var coordenadas = PolylineOptions()
    for (punto in puntos){
        coordenadas.add(punto.start_location?.toLatLng())
        coordenadas.add(punto.end_location?.toLatLng())

    }
```

Comment: se me ocurren unas soluciones, pero dependera mas de como este tu proyecto. Puedes intentar mejor que en lugar de ver el final de la polilinea, compares tu ubicacion actual vs tu ubicacion destino y calcules la distancia, y cuando esa distancia sea menor a "x", lanzas tu activity. O la otra opcion, utilizar el servicio de google para calcular una ruta. Entre todos los parametros que te regresa, uno es la polilinea y otro es la distancia y lo mismo, comparar la distancia del json respuesta vs un "x" para determinar si lanzar el activity

Comment: Si eh tratado de comprar mi ubicacion actual vs la de end_location pero no funciona :(

Comment: para que coincida tu ubicacion actual vs tu punto final de manera exacta es complicado si es que lo estas haciendo asi:  `(latOriginal == latDestino && lonOriginal==lonDestino)`. Para este caso es mejor hacer algo como esto: `float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);` , eso te regresa una distancia en metros aproximada. Aca la documentacion de [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)